# D3.js SVG drop shadow for fast transitions

Tags: d3.js, css, transition, dropshadow

What is the best way to do drop shadows for fast transitions?  I have tried using filter with the code below, but it seems like it makes my transitions much more choppy (i have a maybe 20 or so rectangles that move around):

```
var shadow = vis.append("defs").append("filter")
    .attr("id","dropshadow")
    .attr("height","130%");

shadow.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in","SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation","3");

shadow.append("feOffset")
    .attr("dx","2")
    .attr("dy","2")
    .attr("result","offsetblur");
```

Is there any cross-browser CSS dropshadow for modern browsers? (ie9+,chrome,firefox...don't care to support others)

Is there any way to speed up transitions with this type of shadow?

Is there any alternative method?  Should I just draw another rectangle behind it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for CSS drop shadows then the property you're looking for is `box-shadow`. It is supported from IE9 and up and takes four properties:

- The horizontal offset of the shadow
- The vertical offset
- The value by which the shadow must blur
- And then its spread

It also responds to transitional changes if you're hoping to animate the shadow itself in some way.

You can view more at the W3 link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) where they go more in-depth.